# Mysql: if else from one column to another column

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if there is any chances to insert into a table from another table if value = '0' then import = 'no' else import = 'yes'

Now is on automatically 'yes' on insert.

My sql query:

```
insert into table_3 (name, data, type, value, import)
select name_batch, data_of_insert, 'File 2', SUM(value), 'yes'
from table_2
WHERE data_of_insert > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
group by name_batch");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE`:

```
insert into table_3 (name, data, type, value, import)
select name_batch, data_of_insert, 'File 2', SUM(value), 
    case when SUM(value) = 0 then 'no' else 'yes' end
from table_2
where data_of_insert > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
group by name_batch
```

The above works only if `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is disabled.

If not, use:

```
insert into table_3 (name, data, type, value, import)
select name_batch, data_of_insert, 'File 2', SUM(value), 
    case when SUM(value) = 0 then 'no' else 'yes' end
from table_2
where data_of_insert > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
group by name_batch, data_of_insert
```

Comment: as @roy now is not even inserted the date into table 3

Comment: i figured it out :) it was a problem on my column name, it's working perfectly thx

Answer (score 0):

Check this and tell me if works!.

```
insert into table_3 (name, data, type, value, import)
select name_batch, data_of_insert, 'File 2', SUM(value), IF(SUM(value)=0, 'no', 'yes') as value
from table_2
WHERE data_of_insert > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
group by name_batch");
```